# Cannot Create User Profile in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-redux

First off, thanks for taking the time; this is my first question posted!

I'm in the middle of coding my first mobile application in React Native: a stats managing App for my fraternity. Right now, I would like an admin user to be able to add other users to the app and set their initial profile information (first name, last name, position, dues paid etc).

Once they submit the details, the code below tells firebase to create a new user using the provided email and password, then adds their other profile information under the user parent in the Realtime Database.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(key);
    firebase.database().ref('/ChapterName/users/' + key)
    .set({ firstName, lastName, rank, position, goodStanding, dues, communityService, chapters, mixers, brotherhoods });
  })
```

The JSON tree created can be seen here: [Firebase Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkRAa.png)

My problem is that when the new user logs in, I cannot find a way to access their profile information...ideally, I would set the key of each child under 'user' to the user's email: that way they could login and I could match their email to the key of their profile info and fetch it that way. Unfortunately, keys must be UTF-8 encoded and don't allow for me to include '@ or .'

Does anyone know a way around this? I feel as if the firebase Admin API could be a solution but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside react-native with firebase, if they user already login and you already integrate firebase with redux, you can access the current user information inside redux using this line

```
state.firebase.profile
```

as per my suggestion, I think it's best for to integrate 
react-native app + react-native-firebase + react-redux-firebase

thus, you dont have to use web firebase function as it's already exist in props.

if you need to update the profile after user already created you can use something like this

```
this.props.firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {

        this.props.firebase.updateProfile(
          {
            name: 'Hazim',
            age: 24,
            mode: 'Rampage'
          }
        )

      }).catch((error) => {
        //Error value
      })
```

and inside any component, you can get current user info with connect function like this.

```
class Home extends Component {

}

export default compose(
  firebaseConnect(),
  connect( state => {
    profile: state.firebase.profile
  })
)(Home)
```